# Username "Tab" Completion in Comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app

Could we get comment username completion in the SE app?  It's extremely handy with some of the longer usernames on the desktop site.

Comment: Do you not get the user name if you start `@us`? You should get the name of the user(s) who've commented so that your comment is addressed to them (as well as the OP).

Comment: I get that on the desktop site, but not the Android app.